# BigCommerce add products to cart programmatically and redirect to checkouts page

Tags: api, checkout, bigcommerce

I am building an app for Bigcommerce app store for which i need to add products to a user's cart programmatically and redirect him/her to the checkouts page for payment processing.

I have done some hacking around the products page to get the form data that is passed to build the cart. This works fine when trying out with curl or with Postman in Chrome. However, it gives a cross domain access denied error when trying the same thing programmatically.

Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Do you mean this part, `/cart.php?action=add&product_id=`, gives you a cross-domain error?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use some javascript paired with the stencil-utils API in Stencil themes. An example of the syntax of that code is:

```
/*  
* Import all product-specific js 
*/
[...]
import utils from '@bigcommerce/stencil-utils';
[...]
addProductToCart() {
  utils.hooks.on('cart-item-add', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

This interacts with the following html and data tag:

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="{{product.cart_url}}"
enctype="multipart/form-data" data-cart-item-add>
```

In Blueprint or Stencil, you can build a URL to add an item to the cart with `site.com/cart.php?action=add&sku=INSERT-SKU-HERE`. You can then check a referral url and execute a javascript redirect to checkout based on that referrer.

```
if (document.referrer == "site.com/cart.php?action=add&sku=INSERT-SKU-HERE") {
window.location.href = "site.com/checkout.php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript for this case:

```
var productId = '112';
location.href = '/cart.php?action=buy&product_id='+productId;
```

This will add the product to cart and redirect the customer to the checkout page.